# How do i simulate this event.observe if the field is not available

Tags: jquery

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
if ($('qty')) $('qty') .observe('blur', function(e){
optionsPrice.reload();
```

i removed the quantity field so not my custom options price is not updating can anyone help me with this,  Many thanks in advance

Comment: `observe()` is prototype method. not jquery. for jquery it is `on()`

Comment: ok thanks for that then how if its possible can i change this code so that i am able to achieve the desired outcome? Thanks again

Comment: do you want jquery solution for observing a blur event on a dynamically added field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 'qty' is id of the dynamic element

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery(document).on('blur', '#qty', function(e) {
    optionsPrice.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks arun this works perfectly the problem that i've been having is that i have removed the qty field for some of the products meaning that the price does not dynamically update.  I was wondering if their is a way of simulating this event so that the price still dynamically updates or maybe a way of having this look at another custom option in the event that qty is not available, thanks again this ones had me for around a week now.

Comment: or maybe this is achievable by adding a hidden field to the page so that the jquery will use this as an alternate, i;m pretty novice with jquery just trying to think of options.  thanks again

Comment: @user3126785 have you solved your problem? if not, please explain it since i do not understand the explanation given here in the comments

Comment: @user3126785 I'm guessing you are new to stackoverflow.com. When you see a correct answer for your question, please accept it as the correct answer by clicking the tick mark on the left side of the answer so that future users will know what answer solved your problem

Comment: well sorry i will try again to explain, maybe my inexperience showing, so i have actually got qty to dynamically update price using the event.observe and a formula, i use an attribute to remove qty from some of my items as it is not required.  The items I've removed qty from will not update price dynamically any more as qty is no longer on the page.  I was unsure of the problem but it seems it is the method i use to calculate. apologies again and thanks for any help

Comment: the code that goes with my event observe is:var qty;
    if($('qty').getValue().length !== 0 ? $('#qty') : 1 ||    isNaN($('qty').getValue()) || $('qty').getValue() <= 0) qty = 1;
else qty = $('qty').getValue();
price*=qty;

Comment: @user3126785 can you try to create a jsfiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: I've looked at jsfiddle and attempted, I have some jsquery code; I've tried to use but had no luck what so ever, thinking I may be fighting a loosing battle on this one lol

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44962/discussion-between-arun15thmay-and-user3126785)

Comment: i do however see the problem is price*=qty because when qty is not available to multiply by price will be zero